# Selecting nested data from multiple MYSQL tables

Tags: jquery, mysql, select, join

i have to select nested data from multiple tables.

My tables are  betting_sport, betting_groups, betting_leagues, and betting_matches.

Every sport has many groups, groups have many leagues and leagues have many matches.

[image: This is screenshot for my tables]

I want to select nested tree for **sports->groups->leagues** which have only matches that have status=1

I tried this select, but it doesn't work:

```
            select
                betting_sport.id as s_id,
                betting_sport.title as s_title,
                betting_group.id as g_id,
                betting_group.title as g_title,
                betting_league.id as l_id,
                betting_league.title as l_title
            from
                betting_sport
            left join
                betting_group
            on
                betting_group.betting_sport_id = betting_sport.id
            left join
                betting_league
            on
                betting_league.betting_group_id = betting_group.id
            WHERE
                betting_sport.id
            IN
            (
                select betting_sport_id from group where id in (
                    select
                        betting_group_id
                    from
                        betting_league
                    where
                        betting_league.id in (
                         select betting_league_id from betting_match where status=1
                        )
                )
            )
```

Comment: Show some sample dataset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tables have a nice linear relationship structure, so there should be no need for the double-nested queries..

```
SELECT *
FROM betting_sport
LEFT JOIN betting_group ON betting_sport.id = betting_group.betting_sport_id
LEFT JOIN betting_league ON betting_group.id = betting_league.betting_groupid
LEFT JOIN betting_match ON betting_league.id = betting_match.betting_league_id
WHERE betting_match.status = 1
```